# Sum Saturday and Friday row value in panda frame and assign into Friday's row value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the panda dataframe in python below.

```
full_name  serial  Date_YMD        prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    20200922    12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    20200923    12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200924    12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200925    12885.50  12984.25   62295.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200926    12880.00  13000.00   14224.0
```

I want to detect which row falls on a Saturday based on column Date_YMD. Sum the `volume` value on this Saturday and the previous day (Friday) `volume`, then assign the sum into Friday's `volume`.

The final dataframe will look something like this;

```
full_name  serial  Date_YMD        prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    20200922    12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    20200923    12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200924    12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200925    12885.50  12984.25   76519.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200926    12880.00  13000.00   14224.0
```

I am using python 3.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['Date_YMD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d')
m = df['Date_YMD'].shift(-1).dt.weekday.eq(5)
df.loc[m, 'volume'] += df['volume'].shift(-1)
```

---

```
  full_name serial   Date_YMD     prc1      prc2   volume
0  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-22  12874.5  12927.75  61023.0
1  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-23  12878.5  12926.75  61023.0
2  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-24  12872.5  12928.75  61023.0
3  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-25  12885.5  12984.25  76519.0
4  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-26  12880.0  13000.00  14224.0
```